# XOPEN_SOURCE and signal handling

Tags: c, linux, signals, standards

In the following program, if I uncomment `_XOPEN_SOURCE` line, my program terminates when I hit `C-c`, same program doesn't terminate If I don't comment that line. Anyone knows in what ways does `_XOPEN_SOURCE` affect signal handling? I am on linux with gcc (4.6.3) and glibc (2.15).

```
/* #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);

void handle_signal(int signo)
{
    printf("\n[MY_SHELL] ");
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main()
{
    int c;
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGINT, handle_signal);
    printf("[MY_SHELL] ");
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n')
            printf("[MY_SHELL] ");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, `char c`: no, no, no, no, no. `EOF` needs to be out-of-band. That's why `getchar` returns an `int`.

Comment: @Dave You are right. It was actually an example I found on internet. I didn't notice it. Fixing that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `signal()` function can have two different forms of behaviour when installing a signal handling function:

- System V semantics, where the signal handler is "one-shot" - that is, after the signal handling function is called, the signal's disposition is reset to `SIG_DFL` - and system calls that are interrupted by the signal are not restarted; or
- BSD semantics, where the signal handler is *not* reset when the signal fires, the signal is blocked whilst the signal handler is executing, and most interrupted system calls are automatically restarted.

On Linux with glibc, you get the BSD semantics if `_BSD_SOURCE` is defined, and the System V semantics if it is not.  The `_BSD_SOURCE` macro is defined by default, but this default definition is suppressed if you define `_XOPEN_SOURCE` (or a few other macros too, like `_POSIX_SOURCE` and `_SVID_SOURCE`).

Under System V semantics, if the `read()` system call underlying `getchar()` is interrupted by `SIGINT` then `getchar()` will return `EOF` with `errno` set to `EINTR` (this will cause your program to exit normally).  In addition, after the first `SIGINT` the disposition of this signal is reset to the default, and the default action for `SIGINT` is to terminate the process (so even if your program survived the first `SIGINT`, the second would cause it to exit abnormally).

The solution is not to use `signal()` at all for installing signal-handling functions; instead, you should use `sigaction()`, which is portable - it gives the same semantics everywhere.  With `sa_flags` set to `SA_RESTART`, `sigaction()` it will give the BSD semantics, which is what you want.

Comment: But I should note that in any case the program won't terminate when C-c is pressed first time (with the handler already set).

Comment: That's not what's happening here. The `_XOPEN_SOURCE 700` semantics lack `SA_RESTART`, causing `EINTR`, and returning `EOF` in getchar, exiting the program. See my answer.

Comment: @Dave: You quite correct, I have updated this answer with the syscall restarting information.

Answer (score 1):

These subtle behavorial differences are why `sigprocmask()` is usually preferred to `signal()` The version with `_XOPEN_SOURCE 700` defined calls (as shown by strace)

```
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_INTERRUPT|SA_NODEFER|SA_RESETHAND}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x80484dc, [], SA_INTERRUPT|SA_NODEFER|SA_RESETHAND}, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_INTERRUPT|SA_NODEFER|SA_RESETHAND}, 8) = 0
```

Whereas the commented-out one calls:

```
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_IGN, [INT], SA_RESTART}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0 
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x80484dc, [INT], SA_RESTART}, {SIG_IGN, [INT], SA_RESTART}, 8) = 0
```

The important extra flag that `_XOPEN_SOURCE` lacks is `SA_RESTART` which allows the `read` system call to continue as if no signal occured. Without that, the system call indicates failure, `getchar()` returns `-1` (but indicating failure, rather than a true EOF), and your program terminates.